# Handling merge requests in gitorious and pull from remote ref

Tags: git, gitorious

I am trying to use the merge request feature of gitorious.  I can see the merge request but under the heading **Commits that would be merged** I just have an error :

```
An error has occured. Please try again later.
```

[image]

Any ideas how to track that down?  Also in the help section in how to handle the merge request it says something like :

```
# Fetch the merge request into this branch
git pull \
  git://git.site.com/1-10-core/core.git \
  refs/merge-requests/1
```

I tried this but I just get the error

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/merge-requests/1
```

Here is part of what `git config -l` returns :

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@git.site.com:1-10-core/core.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

and this is what is in my `.git/config`

```
 repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@git.site.com:1-10-core/core.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by the remote reference 'refs/merge-requests/1' not existing in the origin repository. Both the Gitorious view of merge request #1 and your git pull operation point to that.